# connect to MYSQL from PHP via terminal

Tags: php, mysql, terminal

I'm trying to connect to my localhost MySQL server via php in the terminal.

It's outputting that it cannot connect to the host through my socket. My PHP ini install says this

```
MYSQL_SOCKET    /tmp/mysql.sock
```

so i used

```
mysql_connect("/tmp/mysql.sock","root","","");
```

And I get errors

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
mysql_connect(":/tmp/mysql.sock","root","","");
```

like [mentioned in the manual](http://de.php.net/function.mysql-connect).

BTW: Posting what errors you get might help when asking questions.